# error missing 1 required positional argument python and thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I tried to use thread to get better run-time result for some reasons the error

> Missing 1 required positional argument: year is keeping popping on the
>   screen

here is the function:

```
def calculate_the_gain_per_month(self, month, this_year):

self.cur.execute("SELECT following_number FROM data_analysis WHERE month = ? AND year =?", (month, this_year))
result_per_month = self.cur.fetchall()

list_of_following_per_month = []  # list of the following number for each day in the current month
gain_following = []  # list of gain of following per day in the month

for each_day in result_per_month:
   list_of_following_per_month.append(each_day[0])

for index in range(len(list_of_following_per_month) - 1):
                    gain_following.append(list_of_following_per_month[index + 1] - list_of_following_per_month[index])

return gain_following

def calculate_the_gain_per_year(self, year):

threads = [threading.Thread(target=insta_sql.calculate_the_gain_per_month, args=(month,year)) for month in range(12)]

for thread in threads:
  thread.start()
```

Comment: What is `insta_sql`?

Comment: hi insta_sql is the name of the call that I take the function from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure how your whole construct looks like, but the following should work...

```
from threading import Thread

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.calculate_the_gain_per_year(2000)

    def calculate_the_gain_per_month(self, month, this_year):

                print("SELECT following_number FROM data_analysis WHERE month = {} AND year ={}".format(month, this_year))

                list_of_following_per_month = []  # list of the following number for each day in the current month
                gain_following = []  # list of gain of following per day in the month

                for index in range(len(list_of_following_per_month) - 1):
                    gain_following.append(list_of_following_per_month[index + 1] - list_of_following_per_month[index])

                return gain_following

    def calculate_the_gain_per_year(self, year):

        threads = [Thread(target=self.calculate_the_gain_per_month, args=(month, year)) for month in range(12)]

        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()


a = A()
```

Of course you can also call it from outside of the class using the class object `a.calculate_the_gain_per_year(2000)`.

Comment: I wish I can I have less the 15 reputation so it doesn't allow me to accept it

Comment: I don't think that this is a restriction for accepting an answer, but okay :)